# Dual-booting Ubuntu 20.04 hangs, but works fine in recovery mode

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I'm running a Dell 9510 XPS, dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.  The machine has two 2TB NVMe SSDs - drive 1 has Windows 10, plus the root and swap partitions for Ubuntu; drive 2 is for the Ubuntu /home.  Booting up displays the GRUB menu, and selecting Windows does what is expected - it starts Windows.  But if you select Ubuntu, it just hangs.  If you restart and select Advanced options and recovery mode, it will display the verbose start-up commands, then present the recovery options menu.  If you then choose Resume, it will boot into Ubuntu with no issues.

I have read elsewhere in the forum that editing the GRUB menu to add "dis_ucode_ldr" to the end of the "ro quiet splash" line has fixed this issue for some people, but it didn't work for me.  Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: In windows is fast boot disable and secure boot disabled? Is windows been shut down properly before you later try to run Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there any hint as to why the system is hanging in `/var/log/syslog` or one of the recent `/var/log/boot.log.X` files? 

Comment: Recovery mode uses nomodeset. What video card/chip do you have? If nVidia you may need to install nVidia from Ubuntu repository. You can use command line or in gui, System Settings & driver tab.

Comment: Hi folks.  To answer your questions...

Comment: David: Yes, both Fast Boot and Secure Boot were disabled, and Windows was shut down properly.  Matigo: I had a good long look at the log, but nothing appeared to stand out as an obvious error.  Oldfred: its an Nvidia Geforce RTX 3050 Ti chipset.  I have the correct and most recent drivers installed but they don't seem to be working properly, no matter what I try.

Comment: But I'm not sure if the failure to boot is a result of not having the driver set up properly, or if the driver is not being set up due to the boot failure.  So I decided to start over again, and as I type this I'm reinstalling Ubuntu.  I'll get back to you later today.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu, but still having the same issue.  I've tried removing all the Nvidia drivers and reinstalling it from the Dell support site, but no joy.  I'm sure I'm not the first person in the world (or the only one) who has hit this problem.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, moreover, when I plug in a second screen into my HDMI port, it does not detect it. I'm on Ubuntu 22 LTS and this issue started happening recently for me.